# Why does this code to generate unique random numbers use `=== -1`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I found this code to generate unique random numbers. I don't understand what this part of code does--or more importantly, why do we need `=== -1`? It cannot be equal to -1 as far as I know.

```
var arr = [];
while(arr.length < 8){
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
    if(arr.indexOf(r) === -1) arr.push(r);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 when the element is not found

Comment: `.indexOf` returns `-1` when there is no index, because `0` is an index. Perhaps they should have made it return `false`, but they didn't.

Comment: FWIW: a better/alternative version of this would be a shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

It's supposed to mean "when the element is not found in the array, push the element to the array".

`arr.indexOf(r) === -1` -> When the element is not in the array, this is going to be true. That's because no element in the array is going to have an index of -1. The first element has an index of 0, and then 1, 2, 3 and so on.

Maybe it's a better idea to use includes():

```
if(!arr.includes(r))
```

This makes the condition more readable.

Answer (score 0):

It checks if "r" is already in the array. If it is, it will not push/add "r" into the array arr.